# Long form validation in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a long long long form. It has about 200 fields. Now, about 50 fields need to be validated through JavaScript / jQuery. How can I easily validate them without a huge amount of code. I want to avoid doing this:

```
field1 = document.getElementById("field1").value;

if (field1 == '') {
   alert ("Please enter a value for Field1");
   return false
}
```

Is there an easier way? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's impossible to say with your current question details. Is it just that you need to validate that they are not empty? Or do some require custom validation?

Comment: both, checking for empty ones and checking for certain conditions

Comment: Did anyone give you a correct answer? Please check it if so =)

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery Form validation plugin and assign the correct classes to the fields.

It's as simple as `class="required"` in most cases!

Comment: I thought about this too, but the plugin can be a bit difficult to use. Do you know if it allows to display an alert box when an error is found, instead of the actual displaying on the page? That's a bit too much for this form. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The plugin is a one liner to get the class="" functionality. It can't get any simpler than that... Also you can surely modify the plugin so it uses alert() instead!

Comment: You _could_ modify the plug-in to use alert(), but that doesn't mean that you _should_. Check out the "Error Containers in Action" examples here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html We've used this plug-in on forms with over 1,000 fields (don't ask) and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if the field is empty or not you could do something like this using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input class="validate" type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input class="validate" type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input class="validate" type="text" />
</form>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('.validate').each(function() { //this will get every input marked with class "validate"
    if ($(this).val() == '')
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [JQuery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) can be much help. You can control the way plugin works from your HTML code and even not write any javascript! If you need more complex validatio, you can extend it by adding specific validation functions. It allows you to localize the application as well.

This page gives a good example on how to use the plugin: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/ (click the "Show script used on this page" link).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary fiddle, that you can use to validate your form, Just add a span after each of the fields that you need to validate.

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/h2S6G/35/

Answer (score 0):

> I thought about this too, but the plugin can be a bit difficult to
>   use. Do you know if it allows to display an alert box when an error is
>   found, instead of the actual displaying on the page? That's a bit too
>   much for this form. Thanks a lot

Here's a validator I wrote that uses a pop-up style alert box for error messages. Is that the sort of thing you are after?
http://validator.codeplex.com/

Do you want default error messages like for required validator? Regarding [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) was it the syntax it offers to place validation information in the method call you found difficult since for a large form having validation information located separately from the text boxes makes it harder to go through and verify all fields have the right validators and messages?